# Filter by or with?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, by-with

**Should I say:**

I want to **filter** users list **by** names.

**OR :**

I want to **filter** users list **with** names ??

Comment: Use *by*. *With* suggests the agent by which you will filter (or alternatively, the type of list you want to filter), rather than the criterion.

Comment: Note that you filter by _name_, not _names_ - unless each user has multiple names. As @Lawrence indicates, _a list with names_ probably indicates that names are in the list, not that you want to use _name_ as a criterion to filter the list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To choose either 'by' or 'with', you need to see if the phrase/word that comes next indicates a **method** or an **instrument**. If you want to show a method, you use *by*. If it's an instrument with which the activity was done, you use *with*:

- I opened the bottle *by* removing the cap
- I opened the bottle *with* a corkscrew
- I hit him *by* using a bat (the method is *using* something)
- I hit him *with* a bat

In your case, 'names' are a method used for filtering users list, not an instrument. So, you have to use 'by'. See the examples below:

I want to filter the users list *by names*

I want to filter the users list *with a software* that filters user lists *by name*

Comment: Not comprehensive. The clothing was sorted by John (volitional agent). The difficulty comes with: The sweets are sorted into different colours by this new machine (non-volitional agent?).